# WPF Ribbon combobox select default item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, ribbon

How do I select, for example, the first value `Select` to appear by default as selected item when control is displaied. Currently does not appear nothing.

```
 <RibbonComboBox Width="50" Margin="0,0,0,2" DisplayMemberPath="Select"> 
                <RibbonGallery SelectedValue="Select">
                    <RibbonGalleryCategory >
                        <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Select" />
                        <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Expand" />
                        <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Collapse" />
                    </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                </RibbonGallery>
            </RibbonComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a property SelectedIndex and bind it to Combobox. Then SelectedIndex = 0 will select first item in combobox